# Application Insights does not log successful requests

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have added Azure Application Insights to a number of my .Net WebAPI applications. I've noticed that I do not receive successful request telemetry from these applications. I do receive dependency telemetry and failed requests but not the actual telemetry that the request has been made. By fudging the URL or the request and forcing a failure, I can see that get sent to AI, so my issue is definitely not with the instrumentation key.

I initialize the instrumentation key as follows:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey =
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsightsKey"];
```

I have attempted to remove AI from the application entirely and added it again using the Configure Application Insights option but it still does not work. There is another of my web apps that uses AI that was configured a while back and it works perfectly, I have replaced the set up of the broken app with that of the working app and also made the package versions line up but I still only get telemetry for failed requests. The capture below from the Live Stream shows this, the red arrow points to the dependency calls made for the successful request, yet nothing shows in the Request Rate graph for it. In contrast there is a failure before it, and that is logged.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer for this in a solved issue on the Application Insights Github. The solution is to open your ApplicationInsights.config and scroll to the telemetry module Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule below it comment out the line System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler

This issue has been fixed and is due to go out in version 2.5 of the packages. You can read through the issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/175

Answer (score 0):

Try below one, it works for me:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration configuration = Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

configuration.InstrumentationKey = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstrumentationKey"];
```